# Vscode pytest test discovery fails due to missing environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have config.py module that loads environment variables necessary for connecting to MongoDB.
When I try to run the test discovery in vscode pytest doesn't find these environment variables.
In the test files, I use some methods from a module that imports the config module, so the code that reads these env vars always run.

The environment variables are defined in my .bashrc file.

Pytest alone can run the test using these environment variables if I run it from the terminal

python /home/orch/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- -s --cache-clear tests

That's the command vscode runs when activating the tests discovery tool

I expect the vs code to find the tests

the out is the following error:

```
tests/test_db.py:5: in <module>
    from src.core.db import MongoHandler
src/core/db.py:5: in <module>
    from src.core.loggers import gcl_log_event
src/core/loggers.py:8: in <module>
    from configuration import config
configuration/config.py:22: in <module>
    user_name = os.environ['EVO_DB_USER_NAME']
../../.local/share/virtualenvs/evolve-sjbSOQds/lib/python3.7/os.py:678: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'EVO_DB_USER_NAME'
```

Comment: Have you re-opened vscode after setting the env vars ?

Comment: Yes, I believe the problem is much more complicated than that :(

Answer (score 31):

I had a similar problem and solved it by declaring an environment variable file .envs in my workspace folder which could look like:

```
EVO_DB_USER_NAME=<your_name>
OTHER_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=<other_name>
```

With this, you can then extend your .vscode/settings.json as:

```
{   
    ...,
     "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.envFile":   "${workspaceFolder}/.envs",
    ...,
}
```

Such it imports the environment variables, before running the test discovery.

Further, you find this discussed in following [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6891) of visual studio code.

Comment: What if it's a typed-in varaible not from a file? Like the ENV from `ENV=testing python3 -m unittest tests/tests.py`.

Comment: If you call it `.env` instead of `.envs`, you shouln't need to modify your configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short... installing `pytest-dotenv` package may solve this problem.

---

Since it has been more than 2 years, maybe this isn't a problem for you anymore...

But I was just facing the same problem - `pytest` not respecting my `.env` file in a vscode python project - and I found this python package called [pytest-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-dotenv/) (with [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)) which solved the problem for me.

With the project setup of loading `.env` file (which is located in the root of my workspace) for linting and runnng in terminal, and these python packages, I was wable to make `.env` file loaded by the test explorer and `pytest`.

In the shell (after activating my `virtualenv` for my project), I ran to install these packages:

```
$ pip install python-dotenv pytest-dotenv
```

Then in the `settings.json` of my workspace, I put the lines below.  ("app" is the subfolder where all my python files of my project is located in my workspace):

```
{
    ...
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    ...
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "-v", "-s",
        "--rootdir", "${workspaceFolder}/app",
    ],
    ...
}
```

In my `.env` file, I also have `PYTHONPATH` variable pointing to my "app" subfolder with absolute path:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/x/.../.../app"
```

Also, the environment variable "`NEO4J_URI`" - which I want the test to load - is written in the same .env file:

[My `.env` file and its location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwT80.png)

Here is the result

[The test of checking of environment variable "`NEO4J_URI`" being loaded and its result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqXKz.png)

I hope this helps you or some people who are in the same situation...

Answer (score 0):

> The environment variables are defined in my .bashrc file.

If you define them in the file .env in your workspace directory, the default vscode python setting should pick them up from there. This default can be changed.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments :

> By default, the Python extension looks for and loads a file named .env in the current workspace folder, then applies those definitions. The file is identified by the default entry "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" in your user settings (see General Python settings). You can change the python.envFile setting at any time to use a different definitions file.